# Screen Garbled When Trying To Install

Tags: system-installation, gpu

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm trying to install on an HP TouchSmart 320 PC with an integrated AMD Radeon HD 6410 gpu. First I get a purple screen with Ubuntu in the middle but then it goes 'garbled/pixelated.' It did it in install mode and 'try it' mode. Is my gpu not compatible?